# why is new Directory() allowed in Dart?

Tags: class, dart, instantiation

Why is `new Directory("myDir")` allowed in Dart? Its definition says `Directory` is an abstract class.

And in it’s language tour, it says abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that `Directory` is an abstract class, it provides a [*factory* constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors) that returns an instance of a concrete implementation class.